# FCM & Local notifications. Android works, on iOS not

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

Im using a solution with FCM and Local notifications to receive specific push notifications on a channel. Everything works for Android.

I send my push notifications trough Postman to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and that all works pretty well.

However when I add my iPhone, and finished all the installation steps that were needed. The only thing I receive is the print in my console on flutter with the message. I don't receive any kind of notification on the iPhone itself.

```
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  var initializationSettingsAndroid;
  var initializationSettingsIOS;
  var initializationSettings;

  void _showNotification() async {
    //await _buildNotification();
  }

  Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      final dynamic data = message['data'];
    }

    if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message

      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    }

    // Or do other work.
  }

  Future<void> _createNotificationChannel(
      String id, String name, String description) async {
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      id,
      name,
      description,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      playSound: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('not_kiddin'),
      enableVibration: true,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);
  }

  Future<void> _buildNotification(String title, String body) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'my_channel',
        'Channel Name',
        'Channel Description.',
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('not_kiddin'),
        ticker: 'noorderlicht');
    var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'payload');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);

    _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions();

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print(message);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
            onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

        //_showNotification();
        Map.from(message).map((key, value) {
          print(key);
          print(value);
          print(value['title']);
          _buildNotification(value['title'], value['body']);
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(body),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('Notification payload: $payload');
    }
  }
```

Comment: In which case that you dont receive message from IOS? On IOS the FCM will not show banner when App is In Foreground, it will only show when App is in background or Terminated

Comment: @thiennguyen it never receives a message, only when the app is in foreground I receive something in my console when my iphone is connected to my mac. But I never receive a notification, also not when the app is on the background.

Comment: I have the same problem, how you handle it? Can show me? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions();

You need to request for permission in iOS (android dont need).

```
  _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(
          sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
```

Answer (score 0):

FCM messages come in different structures for IOS, in your case remove the 'data' when the platform is IOS like these below.

```
            if(Platform.isAndroid){
              roomId = message['data']['chatRoomId'];
              senderId = message['data']['senderId'];
            }else if(Platform.isIOS){
              roomId = message['chatRoomId'];
              senderId = message['senderId'];
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with this, you mean inside the myBackgroundMessageHandler future?